# Formula bar should show the text instead of cell reference

Tags: excel, text, reference, formula

I have a specific width column which has a long text which is partly hidden due to values in the adjacent columns. I was hoping that the user might be able to read the entire text from the formula bar once clicked on the cell. But since I am referencing the text from a PivotTable the formula bar shows the cell reference and not the text. The text is dynamic and hence the referencing is important for me.

Is there a way I could display the text in formula bar instead of the cell reference?

Comment: Click inside the formula bar -> click [f9].  [Source](http://superuser.com/a/544738/236812)

Comment: @chancea  What a cool way to *Copy -> PasteSpecialValues* !!

Comment: @pnuts Ah, I exited out by hitting [Esc] so I didn't have to undo.  But I see this could cause issues...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the cell referencing in the background VBA instead of the excel. so the VBA populated the cells and once the cell is selected the entire text shows up in the formula bar